# Webservice Error while using nusoap.php

Tags: web-services, nusoap

I am trying to create a php web service using nusoap lib. My code is reproduced below.

include("lib/nusoap.php");

$server = new soap_server;

$server->register('login');

function login($name,$pwd)

{

```
$link=mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("mydb") or $status = 'C';
$query = "select * from users where login='$name' and password='$pwd'";

$result = mysql_query($query);
```

if (!$result) 
    {

```
    return "no such user";
}
else
{
    return "user exists";
}
mysql_close($link);
```

}

// Use the request to (try to) invoke the service
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA = isset($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA) ? $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA : '';
$server->service($HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA);

my php version is 5.3.5
I get the following error 
XML Parsing Error: junk after document element
Location: http://localhost/androidta/webservice/server.php
Line Number 2, Column 1:

Can anybody point me any issue in the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i encountered this problem today as well.
what i did is:

**Change:**
$server = new soap_server;

**To:**
$server = new soap_server();